# MS Teams not allowing log in with Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Trying to implement Stack Overflow on MS Teams and members of the team are all getting this error when trying to log in:

> Microsoft Teams integration setup canceled
>
> This Microsoft Teams integration is already associated with the Office Scripts Team, of which you are not a member.
>
> Only one Microsoft Teams organization may be linked to a Stack Overflow Team.

[image: error]

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 7):

Each team can only be connected to one Microsoft Teams organization. As well, each Microsoft Teams organization can only be connected to one team. As the error says, your Microsoft Teams organization is already set up with another team and cannot be integrated further.

If you know who the admin is of the other team / who set up the integration, you can talk to them and request they remove the integration if it needs to be installed somewhere else. Otherwise, the additional teams will not be able to set up the Microsoft Teams integration as long as it remains connected.